# Can a Java Applet use the printer?

Tags: java, swing, applet

Can a Java Applet able to print out text/html easily to standard printer driver(s) (with all common platforms Win/Mac/Linux)?

Does it need to be signed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To print you will either need to use [Signed Applets](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html) or if an unsigned applet tries to print, the user will be prompted to ask whether to allow permission.

Here is some sample code for printing HTML using JEditorPane:

```
public class HTMLPrinter implements Printable{
    private final JEditorPane printPane;

    public HTMLPrinter(JEditorPane editorPane){
        printPane = editorPane;
    }

    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex){
        if (pageIndex >= 1) return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)graphics;
        g2d.setClip(0, 0, (int)pageFormat.getImageableWidth(), (int)pageFormat.getImageableHeight());
        g2d.translate((int)pageFormat.getImageableX(), (int)pageFormat.getImageableY());

        RepaintManager rm = RepaintManager.currentManager(printPane);
        boolean doubleBuffer = rm.isDoubleBufferingEnabled();
        rm.setDoubleBufferingEnabled(false);

        printPane.setSize((int)pageFormat.getImageableWidth(), 1);
        printPane.print(g2d);

        rm.setDoubleBufferingEnabled(doubleBuffer);

        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

Then to send it to printer:

```
HTMLPrinter target = new HTMLPrinter(editorPane);
PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
printJob.setPrintable(target);
try{
    printJob.printDialog();
    printJob.print();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: As Neil COffey's answer, you do not need to sign.

Comment: Thanks for great code!  However, one issue with my testing data:
testPanel.setText("<html> <h1>This is a test print</h1> blaa blaa </html>");

The output on paper has HTML tags visible, so its not formatting e.g. header, it just outputs H1 tags.

Comment: Tom you have to have it use the HTMLEditorKit. Try testPanel.setContentType("text/html") before setting html content with setText

Comment: what are all the necessary imports to make this run?

Answer (score 5):

In order to print, the security manager needs to allow it to access the printer. This means either signing the applet or, at least with **recent versions** of Sun's Java plugin, **if an unsigned applet tries to print, the user will be prompted** to ask whether to allow permission.

Comment: Wew! I would hate if a random site starts printing spam on my sheets... :-)

Comment: PhiLho: There is a dialog box. JavaScript can do the same.

Comment: Neil Coffey: Recent versions? It's been there for a decade.

Comment: Tom -- thanks for the correction -- is it really that long...? You've suddenly made me feel very old!! :-)

Comment: Even newer versions of the JRE can deploy the applet using JWS and use the `javax.jnlp.PrintService`.  It is similar in feel to the 'prompt/print' of an untrusted applet.