# Send JTable to printer via Java applet

Tags: java, swing

I need guidance regarding how to send a table in java applet to a printer connected to the system. It shouldn't involve internet. Is it possible in Java swing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same question asked earlier here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438397/can-a-java-applet-use-the-printer

Comment: @josh Yeah, I noticed. Thanks. I have modified my question now. Kindly check it out.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/563757-printing-from-java-applet/
Is your applet signed?

Comment: I have modified my question, Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
myJTableInstance.print();
```

to open a dialog, that lets you select your printer.